# invariance of $ds^2$ and transformation properties of $dx^i$

Tags: differential-geometry, tensors

Invariance of $ds^2$ and transformation properties of $dx^i$
$$ ds^{\prime2}   =    ds^{2}$$

$$g_{ij}^{\prime}dx^{\prime i}dx^{\prime j}    =    g_{ij}^{\prime}\frac{\partial x^{\prime i}}{\partial x^{k}}dx^{k}\frac{\partial x^{\prime j}}{\partial x^{l}}dx^{l}$$

$$    =  g_{ij}^{\prime}\frac{\partial x^{\prime i}}{\partial x^{k}}\frac{\partial x^{\prime j}}{\partial x^{l}}dx^{k}dx^{l}
 $$

$$ = g_{kl} dx^{k}dx^{l} $$
where $g_{ij}$ is metric tensor

1)I want to ask that idea behind this transformation  is  because  distance remains invariant under transformation to different coordinate system

2) How this new variable $k,l$  are
 introduced

the text i am reading is [physics pages](http://www.physicspages.com/2013/03/18/metric-tensor/)

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes. The metric $g_{ij}$ is the relationship between the purely mathematical coordinates and the physical properties of your manifold. When you change the coordinates, you change the metric too, which makes up for the change.
2. The method for changing coordinates is $$dx'^{i}=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{\partial x'^i}{\partial x^k}dx^k,$$ so $k$ is just a "dummy variable" which iterates through the sum. The Einstein summation convention is to leave out the explicit $\Sigma$, and have the summation be implied by the repeated use of indices. Thus, $$dx'^{i}=\frac{\partial x'^i}{\partial x^k}dx^k,$$ where a summation from $k=1$ to $n$ is implied. So $k$ does not really factor in to the expression. Indeed, if $n$ is known (I'm guessing it's four in your case), we could explicitly write out each term in the sum, but that would get very tedious. The same goes for $l$.